# How are these subalgbras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

This question was prompted by the following [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/726119/73381):

If $X$ is compact then $C(X)$ is a Banach algebra and if $U$ is an open subset of $X$ then $C_0(U)$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$. Here $C(X)$ is endowed with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $C_0(U)$ denotes all continuous functions $f:U \to \mathbb C$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ the set $\{u : |f(u)|\ge  \varepsilon\}$ is compact.

I don't understand how $C_0(U)$ can be a subset of $C(X)$: $f \in C_0(U)$ is only defined on $U$. In order for it to be in $C(X)$ it would need to be defined on $X$. How does this work?

Here's another example: Take $A$ to be the disk algebra. Then $C(S^1)$ is a subalgebra of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand how $C_0(U)$ can be a subset of $C(X)$

Unless $U = X$, it isn't strictly a subset. However, we have a canonical isometric embedding $\eta\colon C_0(U) \hookrightarrow C(X)$ given by

$$\eta(f) = x \mapsto \begin{cases} f(x) &, x \in U\\ 0 &, x \notin U. \end{cases}$$

Since $f(x) \to 0$ as $X$ approaches $\partial U$ for every $f\in C_0(U)$, the extension $\eta(f)$ is continuous, and

$$\sup_{x\in U} \lvert f(x)\rvert = \sup_{x\in X} \lvert \eta(f)(x)\rvert$$

(if one gives the left hand side the value $0$ in case $U = \varnothing$) is easily verified.

For the other example, the disk algebra, the situation is different but similar. Again, we have no strict subset relation, but a canonical embedding. For $f \in A$, the boundary values $f\lvert_{\partial \mathbb{D}}$ are continuous, and the map

$$\iota \colon A \hookrightarrow C(S^1);\qquad \iota(f) = f\lvert_{S^1}$$

is an isometric embedding (due to the maximum principle for holomorphic functions).

When we have a natural (isometric) embedding of one algebra into another, we often tacitly omit the embedding and view it as a subalgebra, not as an algebra isometrically isomorphic to a subalgebra.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Properties) write ''Cauchy's integral formula states that every function holomorphic inside a disk is completely determined by its values on the disk's boundary. '' Does it mean that the disk algebra $A$ and $C(S^1)$ are actually equal?

Comment: No, only some continuous functions on the circle are boundary values of a holomorphic function on the disk. By Cauchy's integral theorem, a necessary condition is that $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} f(z)\cdot z^k\,dz = 0$$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (where, I mention it just in case, $0\in\mathbb{N}$). If that condition is fulfilled, then $f$ is the boundary function of some $F\in \bigcap H^p$, and I think it follows that indeed $F\in A$, but off the top of my head, I'm not 100% sure about the last.

Comment: I am not fully clear on the embedding: does it have to be isometric or is injectivity enough to have a subalgebra?

Comment: We are besides the algebraic structure also interested in the topological structure. Thus we need that the norm given is equivalent to the norm induced by the embedding. If one is strictly concerned with Banach algebras, that is, the algebra together with the specific norm, then to have an embedding of $A$ as a subalgebra of $B$, the embedding must be isometric. If one is more concerned with Banachable algebras, that is, the algebra together with the topology (equivalently, an equivalence class of norms that make it into a Banach algebra), it suffices that the embedding be an algebraic and a

Comment: topological embedding, that is, the given norm on $A$ is equivalent to the norm induced by the embedding into $B$, to say that $A$ embeds into $B$ as a subalgebra. But a merely continuous algebraic embedding is not enough (however, by the open mapping theorem, a continuous embedding of a Banach algebra into another which has closed range is a topological embedding).

Comment: Weird! So to show that $B=\mathbb R$ (with $2$ times the standard norm $d$) is a Banach subalgebra of $A = \mathbb R^2$ (with the standard Euclidean norm) I can't use the map $x \mapsto (x,0)$ because the restriction of the norm on $A$ is only equivalent but not equal to the norm on $B$?

Comment: Kind of. In that situation, it's not a sub-Banach-algebra, only a sub-Banachable-algebra. Just like "an isomorphism in the category of Banach spaces is a surjective linear isometry, but an isomorphism in the category of Banachable spaces is a continuous linear bijection".

Comment: I like your definitions. I had a quick look at [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Banach+space) and was surprised to find that one can apparently choose one out of two non-equivalent definitions for the category of Banach spaces. By the way, did you mean to write ''a continuous linear bijection such that the inverse is also continuous'' in the case of isomorphism in the category of Banachable spaces?

Comment: If we have a continuous linear bijection between Banachable spaces, the Open Mapping Theorem tells us that its inverse is also continuous, so we need not explicitly require it (as we need not explicitly require that the inverse is linear).